# PyQgis - How to update a spatial index?

Tags: pyqgis, spatial-index

I am trying to speed up a QGIS plugin I wrote by adding a spatial index to a vector layer. The aim of my plugin is to simplify a line network by merging some of its features, based on some criteria.

Short version: at each iteration, I delete two features in my layer and create a new one. This works fine. When I do the same thing in my spatial index, the changes do not seem to be taken into account.

My code:

Main function:

```
# Creating the spatial index (works well)
self.spatialIdx = QgsSpatialIndex()
map( self.spatialIdx.insertFeature, featureList )
```

Subroutine (`feature1` and `feature2` are to be deleted and replaced by `mergedFeature`):

```
# Update spatial index (doesn't work?)
self.spatialIdx.deleteFeature( feature1 )
self.spatialIdx.deleteFeature( feature2 )
self.spatialIdx.insertFeature( mergedFeature )

# Update layer (works well)
dataProvider.deleteFeatures( [feature1.id(), feature2.id()] )
dataProvider.addFeatures( [mergedFeature] )
```

When I try to use `self.spatialIdx` later to detect intersecting features (with `self.spatialIdx.intersects( someFeature.geometry().boundingBox() )`), I get the ids of allegedly deleted `feature1` and `feature2` (instead of the id of `mergedFeature`).

So, is there something obvious that I missed? Do I need to call a method to somehow "rebuild" the index? I also have a small doubt about the concept of global variable with `self.…`. Being new to Python, this approach may be wrong.